# What GPU is the Touchmate MID TM-MID777 Tablet?

Tags: gpu

Can anyone tell me the specifications of a tablet called MID TM-MID777 Touchmate?

Is their chipset:

- Adreno
- Mali
- Tegra **or**
- PowerVR?

Comment: Try my answer below, I'm assuming that you meant MID777 (and you just missed a "7" on the end), I coudn't find GPU anywhere in the specs so  I posted a more general answer below.

Comment: From [this](https://carrefouruae.com/webstore/Product.aspx?productid=77901#description) That the model - ARM Cortex processor, would hedge bets its either Adreno or PowerVR as usually goes hand in hand with each other. Tegra/Mali would be more seen with Texas Instruments chips.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot find any reference online to the GPU in the TM-MID777, I thought I'd post this as a general link for any model instead.

Install [CPU Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) from the Google Play Store and run it. It will display all hardware information on your current device.

[image]

This is a sample screenshot, and can be very useful if you are buying a device, or doubt that a device is legitimate. There are a lot of clones out there and this is a great tool for that also.